# Android application, Got error "java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message"

Tags: java, android

i have trouble with my app please i can't fix it. I know the problem at the price = getIntent().getIntExtra("price", -1); line but I don't know how to fix it. i have asked my friend but he sent me here. Please help me this is for my coursework.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

    init();

    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "DrinDB.sqlite", null, 1);
    sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CART(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, " +
            "quantity INTEGER, price INTEGER)");

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (item < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(DrinkDetailActivity.this, "Maaf Pesanan Minimal 1 cup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            try {
                Log.i("TXT PRICE", txtName.getText().toString());
                sqLiteHelper.insertData(txtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        txtQuantity.getText().toString().trim(),
                        txtPrice.getText().toString().trim());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Masuk Keranjang!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                txtQuantity.setText("0");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkDetailActivity.this, CartListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
    int image;
    image = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", -1);
    price = getIntent().getIntExtra("price", -1);
    Log.e("SECOND ACTIVITY", name);

    TextView nameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drink_name_text_view);
        nameTV.setText(name);
    TextView typeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type);
        typeTV.setText(type);
    ImageView imageV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drink_image);
        imageV.setImageResource(image);
        imageV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TextView priceTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.harga_detail_text_view);
        priceTV.setText(Integer.toString(price));

        sumTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sum_text_view);
        priceTotalTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.harga_total_text_view);
        Button incrementBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increment_btn);
        incrementBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                increment();
            }
        });
        Button decrementBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decrement_btn);
        decrementBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                decrement();
            }
        });
}

private void init(){
    txtName = findViewById(R.id.drink_name_text_view);
    txtQuantity = findViewById(R.id.sum_text_view);
    txtPrice = findViewById(R.id.harga_total_text_view);
    btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.pesan_btn);
    btnCart = findViewById(R.id.cart_btn);
}
private void  increment(){
    item++;
    sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(item));
    priceTotalTextView.setText(Integer.toString(sumOfProduct(price)));
}
private void decrement(){
    if(item<1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "maaf Anda tidak dapat memesan kurang dari 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    item =item-1;
    sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(item));
    priceTotalTextView.setText(Integer.toString(sumOfProduct(price)));
}
private int sumOfProduct(int price){
    return item * price;
}
```

}
`

and the error message is here [ at com.dicoding.picodiploma.kedaikopi.Models.DrinkDetailActivity.onCreate(DrinkDetailActivity.java:69)]

**`at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2821)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6295)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:236)
        at com.dicoding.picodiploma.kedaikopi.Models.DrinkDetailActivity.onCreate(DrinkDetailActivity.java:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6834)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2821) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6295) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:793)`**

Comment: Looks like the Log.e doesn't like a null - check for null on `name` and `type` and correct that.

Comment: Hi, you say the error is at com.dicoding.picodiploma.kedaikopi.Models.DrinkDetailActivity.onCreate(DrinkDetailActivity.java:69), maybe you should look there, the intent line is just launching your DrinkDetailActivity, and this activity cannot start. I assume like Andy that you call Log.e with a null message in the 69th line of DrinkDetailActivity.

Comment: hai @Andy i don't know what should i do, where i must change it can you help me

Comment: Post the code which starts this activity assuming it's started by another activity in your application.

Comment: '    private int item = 0;
    private int price = 0;
    TextView sumTextView;
    TextView priceTotalTextView;
    TextView txtName, txtQuantity, txtPrice;
    Button btnAdd, btnCart;
    public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper; ' this? @Andy

Answer (score 0):

When using `Intent.putExtra`, you need to specify a name (first argument) and a value (second argument). The name is always a `String` and **MUST** have the package name as prefix.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

In your example, when you create the Intent to start an Activity, use `intent.putExtra(getPackageName() + ".name", "my name")`. And when you want to extract the extra, use `String name = getIntent().getStringExtra(getPackageName() + ".name")`.

Comment: so i must change my code to the this 'String name = getIntent().getStringExtra(getPackageName() + ".name");' or what? sorry i have no understand android studio @Sebu